# Make WPF UI responsible while reading data from Database

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have C# WPF application which reads data from database then does some work. But the problem is when I am reading data my UI doesn't respond. I have tried Tasks and dispatcher. None of them helps. Code below is in the button_click event. Here is code:

```
DataSet ds;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Task myTask = new Task(new Action(() =>
{
     //GetMyDataSet() returns DataSet
     ds = GetMyDataSet();
     dt = ds.Tables["MyTableName"];
}));

myTask.Start();

while (!myTask.IsCompleted)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

//Continue
```

Comment: Why are you sleeping on the UI thread until the task completes? That's why your UI is unresponsive!

Comment: I think you should use `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal can you recomend me any site which introduces BackroundWorker briefly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, get rid of the sleep-spin, it completely defeats the purpose of using a `Task` since it doesn't allow the UI thread to proceed until the `Task` completes. You don't want that!

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
     new Action(() =>
     {
         DataSet ds;
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();    

         //GetMyDataSet() returns DataSet
         ds = GetMyDataSet();
         dt = ds.Tables["MyTableName"];

         // use Invoke/BeginInvoke to update UI
      }));
```

Now your task will run in parallel with the UI thread until completion. At the end of the `Task` code use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to update the UI. It should be ok now.

Comment: I can't use **Task.Factory.StartNew()**. Am I missing reference or what is problem?

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: @Adil Mammadov: This is very strange. Can you update the code in the question with what you have now?

Comment: And if you'd like a bit different approach, instead of using the `Dispatcher` at the end, you can use task continuation with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. :) After you solve your TPL problems, of course.

Comment: I did What same **Task myTask = new Task.Factory.StartNew()**. But I deleted Thread.Sleep() and wrote logic which I used to read data from DataTable in the same Task. Everything works fine now. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
while (!myTask.IsCompleted)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong. The reason for the UI freezing is exactly this `while` loop which should not exist.

Comment: But he wants the UI to keep responding while the `Task` is working, not block.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { })) simulates "Application.DoEvents" and UI become accessible (process events) every 20 ms. Try simple button handler:         private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }